# Invoke a method by name with factory - what is the best practice solution

Tags: c#, oop

I want to find the best design solution for a home automation project.

I have the following entities:

```
//Switch light on/off
ISwitchable
{
    Switch()
}  

IDevice
{
}

Lamp : IDevice, ISwitchable
{
    Switch()
}
```

If I receive an input from the user to switch the lamp on, I want to invoke the following:
`Lamp.Switch(...)`
Where the switch is a string input.

Ill use the factory method to select a specific device (Lamp) but what about a specific function?

What is the **best practice** solution to invoke a desire method (If it exists).
Is reflection is the way to go or i can think about a design without using reflection?
Thanks!

Comment: you can, for example,  define a common `virtual/abstract` method in base class, say, `Do()`, Every device overrides that method with concrete implementation.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to accept a method name from the user? I voted to close because the question is very unclear, but it seems like you may be overthinking things. A simple `if (inputFromUser == "turnOn") device.Switch(true); else device.Switch(false);` type of construction may be all that's needed.

Comment: Further reading: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) concepts.

Comment: What if the user can send a lot of "operations" such as close ,open, turnon turn off ,changeValue, i'll add a lot of if statments? this is exactly what i want to avoid.

Comment: How many different operations do you think you're going to have for control of a light bulb? Read about YAGNI and KISS. Having a few if statements or a few `switch` cases isn't always a terrible thing. If you concoct something fancier you'll still need to validate the user's input anyway, to prevent them from invoking methods they shouldn't have access to, so one way or another you're going to end up with a list of valid operations in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [strategy pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern) with an [abstract factory](https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) to create the strategies.

Each different "operation" the you describe is one strategy. All of these strategies must implement the same interface (probably a method called something like `Do`/`Invoke`/`Execute` taking a parameter of the device).

The abstract factory is given something to indicate which strategy is required, and returns the specific implementation of that strategy (typically via a `switch`).

Taking one example, you would have a "turn on" strategy implemented by a class, and in the strategy's method, if the device it is given is appropriate (e.g. if it is ISwitchable), it could call the method on that device like this:

```
ISwitchable switchable=device as ISwitchable;
if (switchable!=null)
{
    switchable.Switch();
}
```

At this point you can see that the ISwitchable interface in the question is no use, since you are in an operation that was trying to turn something on, but all it has to work with is a method which will toggle the switch (the device may already be 'on'). But I'm sure you can work out those details. And bear in mind that different operations may need devices to implement other interfaces.

I think the `IDevice` interface in the question is redundant - just use `object`. Certainly [most interfaces with no members are worthless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182128.aspx). It is of more value which of the operational interfaces each device implements, and that should suffice.